# Invalid table constructor options

Tags: tabulator, sveltekit

I'm using Tabulator with Sveltekit.
This is my Tabulator-Component:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { Tabulator } from 'tabulator-tables';
import type { ColumnDefinition } from 'tabulator-tables';
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

export let data: any[], columns: ColumnDefinition[];

let tableComponent: HTMLElement;

onMount(() => {
    new Tabulator(tableComponent, {
        data: data, //link data to table
        columns: columns, //define table columns,
        pagination: true,
        reactiveData: true
    });
});
</script>

<div bind:this="{tableComponent}"></div>

<svelte:head>
    <link
        href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.9.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" />
</svelte:head>
```

The table renders fine, but the pagination and reactiveData option is not working and it says its "invalid":

> [Warning] Invalid table constructor option: – "pagination" (client.js, line 1593)
> [Warning] Invalid table constructor option: – "reactiveData" (client.js, line 1593)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of Tabulator's functionality is split into modules that have to be registered first, or you load everything (which will cause larger bundle sizes than necessary).

To register:

```js
import { Tabulator, PageModule, ReactiveDataModule } from 'tabulator-tables';

Tabulator.registerModule([PageModule, ReactiveDataModule]);
```

([Available modules](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/modules#main-contents))

Or the full import:

```js
import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from 'tabulator-tables';
```

Also, [`pagination`](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/page) is supposed to be a string: `'local'` or `'remote'`